# How to include one jsp file in another jsp with its appropriate output?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am developing a small web application using struts, in my project there will be one jsp file named **AdminOptions.jsp** which gets the **action class(LoginCheck.java) variable value** using **property value tag** and it is displayed. I included the **AdminOptions.jsp** in another jsp file named **DeleteEmployee.jsp** using jsp include tag. While running the project, **DeleteEmployee.jsp** file not displaying the action class variable value which was displayed in **AdminOptions.jsp** it displays null value.
What is the reason?
What is the solution?

Comment: `jsp:include` ?

Comment: yeah  <jsp:include page="AdminOptions.jsp" />

Answer (score 0):

I did't found how you get the value.
Suppose the DeleteEmployee.jsp code as follows

```
<jsp:include page="......./AdminOptions.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="pageValue"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Note the `flush = true` is very important.

Then you can get the value in the DeleteEmployee.jsp by `${param.PageTitle}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<s:push>` tags to push the values to the included JSPs.

Reference:
http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/push.html